# Why does the index in my v-for produce strings instead of 0,1,2,etc?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a snippet of code that I'm having a hard time grasping based on my understanding of Vue.  The code below has a v-for directive that loops through an array of objects.  The index of the v-for is rendered but it shows as a string and not the number I was expecting.  Can someone please help me to understand why that is?  Why is 'Vanilla', 'Strawberry' and 'Chocolate' showing instead of 0,1,2

I've opened up the developer tool to try and understand what's going on but I'm still confused.

```
  <template v-for="(groupFlavor, index) in flavor">
                  <tr v-bind:style="styleRowObject" >
                    <td colspan="5">
                      {{ index }} 
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                </template>
```

Here's the pen for a better perspective:
https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/gOYgPPR?editors=1011

I'm just trying to understand why it's not behaving the way I've seen other examples.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter for Object is the **key** but not **index**.

To get index of element in object you need to use third parameter like below.

> v-for for Object
>
> Parameter 1. value
>
> Parameter 2. key
>
> Parameter 3. index

```
 <template v-for="(groupFlavor, key, index) in flavor">
    <tr v-bind:style="styleRowObject" >
        <td colspan="5">
             {{ index }} 
         </td>
    </tr>
 </template>
```